# Paging 3 - How to scroll to top of RecyclerView after PagingDataAdapter has finished refreshing AND DiffUtil has finished diffing?

Tags: android, paging, android-paging, android-paging-library, android-paging-3

I'm using Paging 3 with RemoteMediator that shows cached data while fetching new data from the network.
When I refresh my `PagingDataAdapter` (by calling `refresh()` on it) I want my RecyclerView to scroll to the top after the refresh is done. In the [codelabs](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-paging#0) they try to handle this via the `loadStateFlow` the following way:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    adapter.loadStateFlow
            // Only emit when REFRESH LoadState for RemoteMediator changes.
            .distinctUntilChangedBy { it.refresh }
            // Only react to cases where Remote REFRESH completes i.e., NotLoading.
            .filter { it.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading }
            .collect { binding.list.scrollToPosition(0) }
    }
```

This indeed does scroll up, but **before DiffUtil has finished. This means that if there is actually new data inserted at the top, the RecyclerView will not scroll all the way up.**

I know that RecyclerView adapters have an `AdapterDataObserver` callback where we can get notified when DiffUtil has finished diffing. But this will cause all kinds of race conditions with `PREPEND` and `APPEND` loading states of the adapter which also cause DiffUtil to run (but here we don't want to scroll to the top).

One solution that would work would be to pass `PagingData.empty()` to the `PagingDataAdapter` and rerun the same query (just calling `refresh` won't work because the `PagingData` is now empty and there is nothing to refresh) but I would prefer to keep my old data visible until I know that refresh actually succeeded.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @P1NG2WIN No, I am using delay of 300ms now which kinda sucks

Comment: :( I will create issue about it then

Comment: @P1NG2WIN did you create the issue? If yes, can you link it here?

Comment: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-paging/issues/149

Comment: @P1NG2WIN and Florian Please check my answer :)

Answer (score 5):

@Florian I can confirm we don't need the `postDelayed` to scroll to top using version `3.1.0-alpha03` released on 21/07/2021.
Also, I managed to make further filter the `loadStateFlow` collection so it doesn't prevent `StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY` to work based on @Alexandr answer. My solution is:

By the time I am writing this, the latest version of Paging3 is `3.1.0-alpha03` so import:

```
androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.1.0-alpha03
```

Then set the restoration policy of your adapter as following:

```
adapter.stateRestorationPolicy = RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY
```

If you have compilation error for the above mentioned change, make sure you are using at least version 1.2.0-alpha02 of RecyclerView. Any version above that is also good:

```
androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha02
```

Then use the filtered `loadStateFlow` to scroll the list to top only when you refresh the page and items are prepended in the list:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            challengesAdapter.loadStateFlow
                .distinctUntilChanged { old, new ->
                    old.mediator?.prepend?.endOfPaginationReached.isTrue() ==
                            new.mediator?.prepend?.endOfPaginationReached.isTrue() }
                .filter { it.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading && it.prepend.endOfPaginationReached && !it.append.endOfPaginationReached}
                .collect {
                    mBinding.fragmentChallengesByLocationList.scrollToPosition(0)
                }
        }
```

The GitHub discussion can be found here: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-paging/issues/149

Answer (score 3):

In cases, such as searching a static content, we can return `false` inside `areItemsTheSame` of `DiffUtil.ItemCallback` as a workaround. I use this also for changing sorting property.

Answer (score 2):

```
adapter.refresh()
lifecycleScope.launch {
    adapter.loadStateFlow
    .collect {                  
        binding.recycleView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)                           
    }
}
```

Comment: This breaks following append operations. At each append the list will be scrolled on top

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the code the condition if loadtype is refreshed.

```
repoDatabase.withTransaction {
            // clear all tables in the database
            if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) {
                repoDatabase.remoteKeysDao().clearRemoteKeys()
                repoDatabase.reposDao().clearRepos()
            }
            val prevKey = if (page == GITHUB_STARTING_PAGE_INDEX) null else page - 1
            val nextKey = if (endOfPaginationReached) null else page + 1
            val keys = repos.map {
                Log.e("RemoteKeys", "repoId: ${it.id}  prevKey: $prevKey nextKey: $nextKey")
                RemoteKeys(repoId = it.id, prevKey = prevKey, nextKey = nextKey)
            }
            repoDatabase.remoteKeysDao().insertAll(keys)
            repoDatabase.reposDao().insertAll(repos)
        }
```

You should delete the condition if LoadType is refresh clear all the tables.

```
if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) {
            repoDatabase.remoteKeysDao().clearRemoteKeys()
            repoDatabase.reposDao().clearRepos()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed the way to improve base code snippet from the topic question.
The key is to listen non-combined variants of properties inside `CombinedLoadStates`

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
            adapter?.loadStateFlow
                ?.distinctUntilChanged { old, new ->
                    old.mediator?.prepend?.endOfPaginationReached.isTrue() ==
                            new.mediator?.prepend?.endOfPaginationReached.isTrue()
                }
                ?.filter { it.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading }
                ..
                // next flow pipeline operators
        }
```

where `isTrue` is Boolean extension fun

```
fun Boolean?.isTrue() = this != null && this
```

So the idea here is to track `mediator.prepend:endOfPagination` flag states. When mediator has completed his part of paging load for the current page, his `prepend` state will not change (in case if you are loading pages after scroll down).
Solution works well both in offline & online modes.

If you need to track prepend paging or paging in both directions it is a good starting point to play around with the another `CombinedLoadStates` properties `append`,`refresh`,`mediator` and `source`

Answer (score 0):

Follow https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingDataAdapter

```
val USER_COMPARATOR = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<User>() {
override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: User, newItem: User): Boolean =
    // User ID serves as unique ID
    oldItem.userId == newItem.userId

override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: User, newItem: User): Boolean =
    // Compare full contents (note: Java users should call .equals())
    oldItem == newItem
}

class UserAdapter : PagingDataAdapter<User, UserViewHolder>(USER_COMPARATOR) {
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserViewHolder {
    return UserViewHolder.create(parent)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val repoItem = getItem(position)
    // Note that item may be null, ViewHolder must support binding null item as placeholder
    holder.bind(repoItem)
}
```

}