# If using room and paging3 together, a manual refresh will cause the list to jump to the 3*loadsize position

Tags: android, android-room, paging, android-jetpack

Version used:

```
room: 2.3.0, 

paging3:3.0.0
```

Devices/Android versions reproduced on:

```
min_sdk = 23

compile_sdk = 30

target_sdk = 24

build_tools = "30.0.3"
```

A manual refresh will cause the list to jump to 3*loadSize (default)

[This](https://github.com/gkj17/Test) is an example of a recurring problem. The reason this problem occurs is that I load more than 3*loadSize of data at once, and insert this data into Room.

If the data is less than or equal to 3*loadSize, this problem will not occur.

---

[This](https://github.com/gkj17/Test/tree/successDemo) is an example of success.

Because my loadSize is 4, so if I load and insert the number of databases at once is less than or equal to 12, then Paging3 will work properly.

But if I load the number of 13 (greater than 3 * 4), then there will be the above problem.

---

Here is the demo video
[image: demo]

Comment: Does the same issue occur with Room version 2.4.* and Paging 3.0.1?

Comment: i tried to use `Room 2.4.0-alpha04 ` and `Paging 3.0.1` ,but it also occured .

Comment: I believe you are having the same problem has listed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68684689/14425729.