# Paging 3, recycler view flickers when i call adapter.retry on footer load state

Tags: android, android-paging, android-paging-library

pagination seems to work well, but when disconnect the internet and call adapter.retry everything works as expected, except that the recycler view flicks,

here's a video https://youtube.com/shorts/9Fw9VyEPGLE?feature=share

I followed android paging codelab to the detail, I just adapted somethings to match my api, nytimes api for movies.

when just scrolling the pagination works as expected, but if i for exemple the user loses connection while scrolling, when/if he reaches the end of the list and tries to reload then the recycler view flicks, but the new load of movies is added perfectly where it should be, so I don't know why the recycler view flickers.

My code;

## RemoteMediator

```
override suspend fun load(
    loadType: LoadType,
    state: PagingState<Int, Movie>
): MediatorResult {

    val page = when(loadType) {
        LoadType.APPEND -> {
            val remoteKeys = getRemoteKeyForLastItem(state)
            val nextKey = remoteKeys?.nextKey
            if (nextKey == null) {
                return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = remoteKeys != null)
            }
            nextKey
        }
        LoadType.PREPEND -> {
            val remoteKeys = getRemoteKeyForFirstItem(state)
            val prevKey = remoteKeys?.prevKey
            if (prevKey == null) {
                return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = remoteKeys != null)
            }
            prevKey
        }
        LoadType.REFRESH -> {
            val remoteKeys = getRemoteKeyClosestToCurrentPosition(state)
            remoteKeys?.nextKey?.minus(1) ?: STARTING_PAGE_INDEX
        }
    }

    try {
        val response = api.fetchMovieCatalog(offset).toMovieCatalog()
        offset+=20
        val movies = response.movieCatalog
        val endOfPaginationReached = movies.isEmpty()
        db.withTransaction {
            if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) {
                db.remoteKeysDao.clearRemoteKeys()
                db.moviesDao.clearMovies()
            }
            val prevKey = if (page == STARTING_PAGE_INDEX) null else page - 1
            val nextKey = if (endOfPaginationReached) null else page + 1
            val keys = movies.map {
                RemoteKeys(movie = it.title, prevKey = prevKey, nextKey = nextKey)
            }
            db.remoteKeysDao.insertAll(keys)
            db.moviesDao.insertMovies(movies)
        }
        return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = endOfPaginationReached)
    }  catch (e: IOException) {
        return MediatorResult.Error(e)
    } catch (e: HttpException) {
        return MediatorResult.Error(e)
    }
}

private suspend fun getRemoteKeyForLastItem(state: PagingState<Int, Movie>): RemoteKeys? {
    // Get the last page that was retrieved, that contained items.
    // From that last page, get the last item
    return state.pages.lastOrNull() { it.data.isNotEmpty() }?.data?.lastOrNull()
        ?.let { movie ->
            // Get the remote keys of the last item retrieved
            Log.e("TAG", "Key - ${db.remoteKeysDao.remoteKeysMovieId(movie.title)}, last item")
            db.remoteKeysDao.remoteKeysMovieId(movie.title)
        }
}

private suspend fun getRemoteKeyForFirstItem(state: PagingState<Int, Movie>): RemoteKeys? {
    // GEt the first page that was retrieved, that contained items.
    // From that first page, get the first item
    return state.pages.firstOrNull() { it.data.isNotEmpty() }?.data?.firstOrNull()
        ?.let { movie ->
            // GEt the remote keys of the first items retrieved
            Log.e("TAG", "Key - ${db.remoteKeysDao.remoteKeysMovieId(movie.title)}, first item")
            db.remoteKeysDao.remoteKeysMovieId(movie.title)
        }
}

private suspend fun getRemoteKeyClosestToCurrentPosition(state: PagingState<Int, Movie>): RemoteKeys? {
    // The paging library is trying to load data after the anchor position
    // Get the item closest to the anchor position
    return state.anchorPosition?.let { position ->
        state.closestItemToPosition(position)?.title?.let { movie ->
            Log.e("TAG", "Key - ${db.remoteKeysDao.remoteKeysMovieId(movie)}, refresh")
            db.remoteKeysDao.remoteKeysMovieId(movie)
        }
    }
}
```

}

## Fragment

```
    override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = FragmentMovieCatalogBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    binding.recyclerView.addItemDecoration(
        DividerItemDecoration(
            context,
            DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL
        )
    )
    binding.recyclerView.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()

    binding.bindState(
        uiAction = viewModel.accept,
        uiState = viewModel.state,
        pagingData = viewModel.pagingDataFLow
    )

    return binding.root
}

private fun FragmentMovieCatalogBinding.bindState(
    uiAction: (UiAction) -> Unit,
    pagingData: Flow<PagingData<UiModel>>,
    uiState: StateFlow<UiState>
) {
    val adapter =
        MovieCatalogAdapter(requireActivity())

    val header = MoviesLoadStateAdapter {
        adapter.retry()
    }
    val footer = MoviesLoadStateAdapter {
        adapter.retry()
    }

    recyclerView.adapter = adapter.withLoadStateHeaderAndFooter(
        header = header,
        footer = footer
    )

    bindList(
        adapter, pagingData, header
    )

}

private fun FragmentMovieCatalogBinding.bindList(
    adapter: MovieCatalogAdapter,
    pagingData: Flow<PagingData<UiModel>>,
    header: MoviesLoadStateAdapter
) {
    swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener { adapter.refresh() }

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        pagingData.collectLatest(adapter::submitData)
    }

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        adapter.loadStateFlow.collect { loadState ->

            header.loadState = loadState.mediator
                ?.refresh
                ?.takeIf { it is LoadState.Error && adapter.itemCount > 0 }
                ?: loadState.prepend

            // show empty list.
            emptyList.isVisible =
                loadState.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading && adapter.itemCount == 0
            // Only show the list if refresh succeeds.
            recyclerView.isVisible =
                loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading || loadState.mediator?.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading
            // show progress bar during initial load or refresh.
            swipeRefresh.isRefreshing = loadState.mediator?.refresh is LoadState.Loading

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that after calling `adapter.retry()` it eventually also ran the code to scroll recycler view to top, but it scrolls before the diffUtil has finished diffing, so it scrolled to a random position at the top of the list.
The solution and the problem has been better presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68684689/14425729)